# Why anticlockwise movement is present in the whole universe

Tags: rotation

Why electronic movement in its orbit and planet orbital movement along with milky ways have anticlockwise movement. is there any specific reason. The Sun is rotating anticlockwise from its axis as well as the earth and other universe are almost have anticlockwise movement what does it prove or there are some reasons which make it clear. (Also there are some spiritual places present in the wold which also show the anticlockwise movement is there any link between all these anticlockwise movement)

Comment: From the southern hemisphere's perspective all is groovy...

Answer (score 1):

Conservation of angular momentum means if a nebula is rotating the systems formed once it collapses will also rotate in the same direction. This is the reason for your observed 'anti-clockwise' rotation. Nothing metaphysical just a simple symmetry of physics.

Answer (score 0):

You say everything orbits counterclockwise, what does that mean? Think of any of the examples you gave, You can look at them from a different point of view and they will appear to be traveling clockwise.

I'd love to see the source of this information. That all electrons and planets only move counterclockwise.